# Hide specific variation attributes displayed in WooCommerce cart items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I want to hide specific variations from the cart page in Woocommerce, I was able to hide all the variation names but I want to keep 3 that need to be shown. The following code shows all the variations in the cart page, would someone know how to apply a filter in here?

```
<dl class="variation">
    <?php foreach ( $item_data as $data ) : ?>
        <dt class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $data['key'] ); ?>: </dt>
        <dd class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $data['display'] ) ); ?></dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

For example I need to hide one of these:

```
<dt class="variation-Kcalperdag">Kcal per dag:</dt>
<dd class="variation-Kcalperdag"><p>1641</p> </dd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not that far! You were just missing a simple conditional statement inside that `foreach` loop. Something like `if ( $data['key'] !== 'Kcalperdag' ):` should do the trick.
I've tested it with a bogus `array` and it seems perfect.

We use the `$data['key']` as a condition to chose if we want to display or not our content.

```
<dl class="variation">
<?php
foreach ( $item_data as $data ):
if ( $data['key'] !== 'Kcalperdag' ): ?>
  <dt class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>">
    <?php echo wp_kses_post( $data['key'] ); ?>:
  </dt>
  <dd class="<?php echo sanitize_html_class( 'variation-' . $data['key'] ); ?>">
    <?php echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $data['display'] ) ); ?>
  </dd>
<?php endif;
endforeach; ?>
</dl>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time, but unfortunately it does not work. It is still showing the variation in the output. Do I not need something like an style="display: none" in the if function?

Comment: No as it's not fetching the value from the database. Make `sure !== 'Kcalperdag'` is the right handle, but it should work. It's working on my end.

Comment: Thank you it worked! Only one question left, I tried to add multiple if statements to hide the other variations, only it duplicated all the information. Any tips on how to add the other variations as well? Thank you!

Comment: `if ( $data['key'] !== 'Kcalperdag' || $data['key'] !== 'Some_Other_Key_1' || $data['key'] !== 'Some_Other_Key'_2 ):` ... etc. Double vertical bars (`||`) means "OR".

Comment: Got it fixed by replacing the || with &&, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To hide specific(s) product variation attribute(s) **displayed** in cart (and checkout), you can use dedicated filter hook `woocommerce_get_item_data` as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'filter_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function filter_cart_item_data( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    // Loop through cart item additional displayed data
    foreach ( $cart_data as $key => $values ) {
        // Target "Kcalperdag" attribute from its displayed label name
        if ( $values['key'] === 'Kcal per dag' ) {
            unset($cart_data[$key]); // Remove attribute from the array
        }
    }

    return $cart_data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.